# How to limit database results to just one?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to limit my database result to one.

the code I have so far is

```
OleDbCommand com9 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Duration], [Flight_Date] FROM Flights WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ? AND [Flight_Date] <= ? AND [Flight_Date] >= ? ORDER BY [Duration] DESC", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
com9.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", p.ID));
com9.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Today));
com9.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6)));
OleDbDataReader dr9 = com9.ExecuteReader();
```

I have tried adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query but this fails.

Does anyone know what I should be using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried adding LIMIT 1 to the end of the query but this fails.

You need to use `SELECT TOP 1` in SQL Server.

`LIMIT` works with other databases like `MySQL`, Postgres`

See: [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

So your query should be:

```
OleDbCommand com9 = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT TOP 1 [Duration], [Flight_Date] FROM Flights 
                                        WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ? 
                                        AND [Flight_Date] <= ? 
                                        AND [Flight_Date] >= ? 
                                        ORDER BY [Duration] DESC", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
```

Looks like you are using SQL Server, you should use `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` objects.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `SqlCommand` class that actually should be used.

Answer (score 3):

`LIMIT 1` works in `SQLite`. Use `SELECT TOP 1` instead as it's supposed to be done in `T-SQL`.

You can also select the percentage of the rows: `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT`

Answer (score 0):

in **SQL Server :** SELECT TOP 1 *  from table;

and

in **Oracle :** select * from table name where rownum=1;